# when do we use ApexPages.StandardSetController in apex class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, extension

I recently started learning and using extensions, but i was not able to understand the use of `ApexPages.StandardSetController Controllername(){}`.

I used it in last two days but i dont know why it is used and when it should be used, i just know if i want to use extension with standard controller then i pass this in the argument of the constructor.

But i also see this used not in the argument but as a method

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController _name_{}
```

what is this ?

The reason i asked is because i see it everytime whenever extensions is use, take the below sample code

```
public class CustomerExt { 
    public Service_Case__c service {get;set;}
    private list <Customer__c> customers;

    public CustomerExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.service = (Service_Case__c)stdController.getRecord();

        customers = [select Name,Id, City__c, Country__c, e_mail__c, 
            Phone_Number__c, Service_Case_Operator__c, State__c, Street__c, 
            Zip_Postal_Code__c 
            FROM Customer__c where Service_Case__c = :service.id limit 1];

    }

    public Customer__c getCustomer() {
        if (!customers.isEmpty())
            return customers[0];
        else 
            return null;
    }
}
```

// Now you should be able to use apex:outputfield:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title=" Customer Stuff"  columns="2" rendered = "{!Customer != null}">
      <apex:outputField value="{!Customer.Name}"/> 
      <apex:outputField value="{!Customer.Country__c}"/> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code? Without context, it's difficult to explain its use. `ApexPages.StandardSetController` is just a class. So it can be used as a type. That's all. And it's sent as argument in an extension constructor to access the current record.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i have edited and added sample code, if you could explain me that.
till now i have only used it in parameter of constructor but with no code inside the braces,i assumed since extension is being used with standardcontroller,the standard controller should be passed as the argument in the extension itself.
in the above code how exactly it helping with the code inside braces for the constructor, what won't be be we able to do if we don't use it.
also sorry if i dont make sense, its been a really long day for me.Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you don't have to use, it's just there.

Long answer, it saves you time.
Here is a [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm#apex_pages_standardcontroller) to the Apex reference.

This class contains every essential method for your overridden pages.

This class contains a standard save(), cancel(), also a getId() and a getRecord() methods.

Let me present you with an example. You have overridden the standard 
*new* action on the standard *Account* sObject. And you're showing a Visualforce page. You could be totally fine without an Apex extension using the following Visualforce code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" title="New Account" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Account" subtitle="Create new" />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Phone}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.AnnualRevenue}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Industry}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.AccountSource}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Type}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Description}" />
                <apex:pageBlockSection />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.ShippingCountry}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCountry}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.ShippingCity}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCity}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.ShippingPostalCode}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingPostalCode}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.ShippingStreet}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingStreet}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

As you can see, we are referencing methods and variables, but without a *controller class*. It is possible, because the standard controller is handling all the dirty work for us.

You should only add Apex class as extension or controller if you're using *custom logic* not handled by the *ApexPages.StandardController* class.

If you're using the *extensions* attribute of an  tag, what is happening in the background is, you're class is extending the *ApexPages.StandardController* class.

These extension classes must have a constructor with a *ApexPages.StandardController* parameter.

After this, you can access the standard controller methods via this parameter.

Please note, the *getRecord()* method is returning the record referenced by the *id* URL parameter and only the fields referenced in the Visualforce page are being returned. This method is not adding the the Query limit so is a good way of accessing the record in context.

Also, the save() method is returning the inserted records detail page as a PageReference, if the DML was successful, else NULL, so the page just refreshes. The cancel() method is returning the PageReference of the URL parameter *retURL*, if the parameter is not present it's default return is the home page of your ORG.

It is very useful and it is encouraged to use standard controllers even if you're using extensions.

If you have any further questions regarding this topic please feel free to ask them.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer Laszlo.
this.service = (Service_Case__c)stdController.getRecord(); - what is this line doing, and at the moment i use public CustomerExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {} without anything  in the curly braces as it gives me error when i dont use it. when should i be using the space inside the curly braces,just an eg situation is appreciated.Also the reason i wanted to understand this was   if you may check this link- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177792/how-to-display-next-last-previous-and-first-buttons-on-a-vf-page-in-accordance-w

Comment: You have to define a constructor for your apex class with _ApexPages.StandardController_ parameter if your apex class is defined to be an extension (defined in Visualforce).

As I wrote, the standard controllers _getRecord()_ method returns the current in context record (defined with _id URL param_).

I assume, the _this.service_ variable is an instance of Service_Case__c sObject.

This line: `this.service = (Service_Case__c)stdController.getRecord();` is casting whatever the getRecord() method is returning to be an instance of Service_Case__c and assigning it to the _service_ variable.

Comment: what if i don't use the standard methods , then i dont have to use ApexPages.StandardController in my extension class right?

Comment: You have to use ApexPages.StandardController in the constructors parameter list only if you're defining a standardController in your Visualforce page.

Comment: cool Laszlo, thanks for the help in this small issue of mine :)