# How to display next,last,previous and first buttons on a VF page in accordance with conditions?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, button, extension

What i want is , to display the next and last button only when its the first page,first,next,last,previous when its 2nd page or more, and first and previous when its last page of opportunities.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  recordSetVar="Opportunities" extensions="opportunityextension2" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblockSection >
                <apex:pageblocktable value="{!opportunities}" var="opp" rows="19">
                    <apex:column value="{!opp.Name}"/> -->
                    <apex:column value="{!opp.ID}"/>
                </apex:pageblocktable>
            </apex:pageblockSection>

            <apex:commandButton value="First" action="{!First}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!Next}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previous}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Last" action="{!Last}" />
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

with this currently all buttons come in all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `getHasPrevious` and `getHasNext` properties directly in your markup. You can merge the property values into properties such as `rendered`, `disabled`, etc. according to your preference:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}" disabled="{!NOT(hasNext)}" />
<apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previous}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}" />
```

Comment: I am sorry but i am not able to understand , can you please brief me on it.

Comment: @Niknit Just add either the `disabled` or `rendered` attribute and set it to merge in `hasNext` or `hasPrevious`.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I added rendered in both and it works, gets hidden when not available.But i think disabled was much better, but how come disabled is not working.i think it disables the button when the value is true, how can i put a twist to it? so that i can make it work with disabled attribute?

Comment: You can use the NOT() function to make sure it uses the reverse of what is in the variable. So your code would look like this disabled="{!NOT(hasNext)}